# JDT-Core and Jasper reports do not work together

Tags: maven, jasper-reports, tomcat6, eclipse-jdt

i have been working with Tomcat 6 and Jasper Reports, but when i start tomcat jdt compiler crash 'cause the jasper jar in tomcat use another version of jdt compiler. I'm working with the lastest version of jasper reports 5.01;

I have been searched this problem on google for 2 days. I found this guy who seems to have the same problem.

http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/10bjk6d3cb/tomcat-jasperreports-and-jar-files

This is the stackTrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem;
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$2.acceptResult(JDTCompiler.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
```

Comment: Did you try editing the class path order in the Build path settings. Try to move the jasper jar below the other jars.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using an incompatible combination of libraries.

The class org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler is trying to use org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem but that method doesn't exist in the Eclsipe library you are using.

I added jasper-compiler-jdt-5.5.15 to my classpath started working... :)